# ClassCastException trying to get AppModule in JDEV

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm a newbie on JDev, so I started this exampleApp. In a page I want to show the name of the department. The page is this

[image]

The **Show name** button goes to a method within a Bean. The Bean is the following:

```
package MBeans;

import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import model.AppModuleImpl;
import Utileria.Util;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl;


public class mbDepartment {
    public mbDepartment() {
        super();
    }

    public void showName(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        AppModuleImpl appModule = Util.getAppModuleImpl();
        String name = appModule.getDepartmentsView1().getCurrentRow().getAttribute("DepartmentName").toString();

         Util.mostrarMensaje(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "The deparment name is " + name, "INFO"); 
    }
}
```

The first line in the showName method is trying to access to the current AppModule in which the department view object resides (If I'm not wrong, again, I'm a newbie), when the code gets to the first line it throws a ClassCastException.

Here's the method of getAppModule that's inside a Util java class:

```
public static AppModuleImpl getAppModuleImpl() {
    JUApplication juApplication;
    juApplication =
            ((JUApplication)BindingContext.getCurrent().getDefaultDataControl());
    AppModuleImpl module;
    module = (AppModuleImpl)juApplication.getDataProvider();
    return module;
}
```

And here's the screenshot of the exception

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumbles with the same problem. I figured it out.

The application module didn't have the application module class, I mean I hadn't had checked the **Generate Application Module Class** checkbox.

[image]